# Does a category of modules in an elementary topos have enough injectives?

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, topos-theory

Let $R$ be a ring object in a elementary topos $X$. Does the category of $R$-modules in $X$ possess enough injectives? If $R$ is a Grothendieck topos, this is a well-known fact, and it is evident in any other examples I can think of, e.g. the topos of sheaves of finite sets on a finite site. The category of $R$-modules does not form a Grothendieck category in this case, lacking arbitrarily large direct sums.

Edit: as an important caveat to point out, the category of Abelian groups in $X$ does **not** have enough injectives. For example in the case $X$ is the topos of finite sets, the category of finite Abelian groups doesn't have enough injectives. If the original claim is true, it is critical that we structure over a ring internal to $X$.

Comment: (Of course, it's enough to interpret and carry out the relevant parts of the Tôhoku paper in intuitionistic higher order logic or something to that effect, but it's far from evident to me that this is possible.)

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but I would imagine that the axiom of choice is required for the usual proof that modules over a ring have enough injectives.  So, you could get a counterexample by just taking a model of (a sufficiently large fragment of) ZF where that fails.

Comment: @EricWofsey I'm a bit doubtful about this: the fact that (unlike having enough projectives) this is true in any Grothendieck topos, not just the category of sets in ZFC, is a concrete sense in which this is intuitionistically valid. Of course, it's entirely possible being a Grothendieck topos in an external universe satisfying choice forces some internal properties on a topos; this isn't really something I know too much about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For instance, Andreas Blass proved in

> *Blass, Andreas*, [**Injectivity, projectivity, and the axiom of choice**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1998165), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 255, 31-59 (1979). [ZBL0426.03053](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0426.03053).

that there are models of ZF in which no nontrivial abelian groups are injective, and such a model is then an elementary topos with a ring $\mathbb{Z}$ whose modules do not have enough injectives.

(This is assuming ZF is consistent, of course, but you can eliminate that assumption if all you're looking for is an elementary topos, since for that you only need a model of a sufficiently large fragment of ZF, and that can be constructed in just ZF using the reflection principle.)